# How to remove decimal value from price using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, rounding

I want to remove decimal point from the price.

My HTML:

```
<span id="product-price-4432" data-price-amount="399" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " itemprop="price">

<span class="price">₹399.00</span>

</span>
```

How can I remove .00 ?

Comment: did you try Math.trunc(decimalvalue)

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method to remove decimal value. 
`Math.round();`

Hope this can help you.

Comment: OP has price value in HTML page so why not getting that value and doing substr?

Comment: Yes substr() is also one of the solution to remove the decimal part of price. And also it is best way when user do not want to change the price amount. because if he use the round method then it will return the round amount of price.

Comment: The OP says ` remove decimal point from the price` and not rounding off the decimal part.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.price').html(Math.floor($('.price').html()));
```

use floor to remove it completely.

using Math.round will result 1.5 to 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` on the price value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var price = $('.price').text();
  var numPrice = price.substr(0, price.indexOf('.'));
  $('.price').text(numPrice)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="product-price-4432" data-price-amount="399" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " itemprop="price">

<span class="price">₹399.00</span>

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = '399.00';
console.log(x);
console.log(parseInt(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var string = '₹399.00'
var thenum = string.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
thenum = Math.trunc(thenum)
alert(thenum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.price').text();
    $('.price').text("₹" + parseInt(text));
});
```